# Would like to reschedule interview due to silly injury. How to convey this?

Tags: new-job, sickness, scheduling

Yesterday I got a very severe sunburn at the beach. I didn't think the symptoms [could be this bad](https://www.healthline.com/health/sun-poisoning#types-and-symptoms) but I've been experiencing confusion and nauseousness. I'm supposed to have an in person interview today. The job itself is relatively physical. I'm still very interested in doing it but I find it very painful to move. I feel like this is a very silly thing to happen and am concerned the hiring manager will think I'm weird. I put on sunscreen but think it washed off in the water.

Should I call or email them to explain this? What level of details should I get? I could get a doctors note, or if they want send photos.

Here is what I'm thinking of emailing.

> Hi,
>
> Am I able to reschedule the interview? I know this is a strange reason
> but I got some heat related illness yesterday. Alternatively can we do a phone interview instead?
>
> Thanks

Comment: You simply state "sudden minor medical problem".  You would never, ever, ever, ever mention - in any way at all - the nature of the problem.

Comment: Actually **sudden minor injury** is the best phrase. That's all you say.

Comment: I agree with @Fattie. And you should never, ever, ever, _ever_ send photos! What were you thinking of? They would never stop talking about it!

Comment: Confusion and nausea? Perhaps you should consider whether more than just a sunburn, e.g., heat exhaustion.

Comment: @Fattie I'm curious why not? I've worked with some people who expect some sort of explanation to be given.

Comment: never go in to personal medical details in business, @thisisaname

Comment: @Fattie I'm still curious why? I don't advise it myself but I can't see how it could be used against them. e.g. "sudden minor injury" if you wanted to be even more vague just say "injury".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to explain exactly what happened. Just a friendly mail saying

> Hi,
>
> Unfortunately I need to reschedule our interview due to a sudden injury. I expect to be available again in [however many] days, could we maybe move the interview to [date/time] or [date/time]?

The last part is optional but at least shows you're thinking along. People get sick suddenly; it happens. Doesn't matter whether it's sunburn or nausea or falling down the stairs or whatever.

An interviewer should understand this and unless you're afraid they'll hire the very first person they can, postponing a few days shouldn't be a big problem.

I would also advise against a phone interview if you're suffering from pain or nausea as you're not going to be giving your best impression. (But it's an option if you think speed is of the essence)

Comment: I would probably replace illness with injury, more to the truth and less likely to shout "COVID".

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul good point. Better English :)

Comment: Good point. I'd go with **sudden minor injury**.

Comment: And be prepared with an answer in case they ask during the rescheduled interview. Get that off the table right up front: "I apologize for requiring that we reschedule, but thanks again for being so accommodating. Everything's OK now." Should be enough.